# Fair assignment distribution algorithm

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm trying to come up with an efficient sql to solve a fair distribution problem.

My data model consists of a 'customer' which can have 1+ 'cases'. 
Each customer needs a 'case handler' which is assigned to look after that customer.

I am trying to distribute the 'customers' across all the 'case handlers' in such a way that all the 'case handlers' have as close to equal amount of 'cases' to each other as possible.

I have a query which gives me a 'Customer Id' and the 'Case Count'

[image: Example]

I have a table of case handlers of which i have currently have 4 in total (case handlers can added or deleted and then this distribution would have to be rerun).

I know i would need to do a join on the case handlers table and the query above so i can then perform an update for each customer to assign them a case handler. But i have no idea on how to do this to balance the cases in the fairest manor.

I have one method that almost worked is that i joined using a modulus on row number of the query by the count of case handlers so each line in the query which was ordered by case count sequentially could then be used to assign a customer to a case handler on a round robin. But this does not give a fair distribution.

(In reality the customer table in my live system is over 100,000 and the majority of them have only one case with less having 2 then even less having 3 etc up to one customer who has 51 cases)

Thanks for any assistance/advice anyone can give me.

Comment: i think what you want is NTILE.  you can google it, or look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14355324/want-to-learn-more-on-ntile

Answer (score 1):

There are formal optimization frameworks that can solve this sort of problem, but I think you might be able to get by with something simpler.  From your description, it sounds like there can be only one case handler per customer, so there is some unfortunate person that needs to handle all 51 cases of your largest customer.

Try something like this (pseudocode):

```
total_cases = SUM(Case_Count)
total_handlers = COUNT(Case_Handlers)

foreach SELECT Customer_Id, Case_Count ORDER BY Case_Count DESCENDING:

   # Calculate the target number of cases to assign to the next handler
   target_cases_per_handler = total_cases / total_handlers

   # If a customer has more than the target number of cases, then
   # it must be assigned to a case handler
   if Case_Count > target_cases_per_handler:
       assign_to_handler(Customer_Id)
       total_handlers = total_handlers - 1
       total_cases = total_cases - Case_Count

   # Otherwise, try to pair up the cases with a small number of cases
   # that is close to average (this part is inefficient)
   else:
       assign_to_handler(Customer_Id)
       residual = CEIL(target_cases_per_handler - Case_Count)
       while (residual > 0)
           best_customer_id, best_case_count = SELECT TOP 1 Customer_Id, Case_Count ORDER BY ABS(Case_Count - residual) ASCENDING

           assign_to_handler(best_customer)
           residual = residual - best_case_count
           total_cases = total_cases - best_case_count

       total_handlers = total_handlers - 1
```

This should give you a rough assignment of customers to case handlers while still ensuring that each client has a single handler.

Answer (score 0):

Your distribution of cases is not too bad.  I would recommend the following approach:

(1) Separate the customers into two groups . . . multiple cases and single cases.

(2) Assign the multiple cases to the case workers in a round-robin fashion.

(3) Assign the single cases to the case workers to balance out each case worker.

This will work for your particular distribution (mostly singletons).  It is not necessarily a general purpose algorithm.

Here is the SQL:

```
with multiples as (
      select CustomerId, COUNT(*) CaseCnt,
             ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by CustomerId order by CustomerId) % @NumHandlers as theHandler
      from customers c
      group by CustomerId
      having COUNT(*) > 1
     ),
    h as (
     select theHandler, SUM(CaseCnt) as CaseCnt,
            SUM(CaseCnt) - (NumCusts / @NumHandlers) as StillNeeded
     from multiples cross join
          (select COUNT(*) as NumCusts from customers c) const
     group by theHandler
    ),
    hsum as (
     select h.*, SUM(StillNeeded) over (order by StillNeeded) as endnum,
            SUM(StillNeeded) over (order by StillNeeded) - StillNeeded + 1 as startnum
     from h
    ),
    singles as (
     select CustomerId, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by CustomerId order by CustomerId) as seqnum
     from Customers
     group by CustomerId
     having COUNT(*) = 1
    ),
    singlesh as (
     select singles.Customerid, h.theHandler
     from singles join
          hsum
          on singles.seqnum between h.startnum and h.endnum
   )
select *
from ((select CustomerId, theHandler
       from multiples
      ) union all
      (select CustomerId, theHandler
       from singlesh
      )
     ) t
```

The SQL pretty much follows the explanation above.  It first randomly assigns the multiple records to handlers in a round-robin fashion.  The handlers are just numbers from 0 to the @NumHandlers.  It then calculates the number of "StillNeeded" cases to get the to max.  As a note:  this assumes that the number of handlers is an exact multiple of the number of customers.  The tweak to fix that makes the query look more complicated.

Then it calculates the number still needed to fill in for each handler.  The key is getting this as a cumulative sum (this uses SQL Server 2012 syntax, in earlier versions you do this with a correlated subquery).  This information is then used to assign the singletons to each handler.

The final step is to `union` the two groups of customers together, the multiples and the singletons.