# Calculating range for a column based on its values

Tags: sql

I have some data like this.

```
 Id  DaysPassed
 1   20
 2   40
 3   8
 4   64
```

Basically, Dayspassed could be any number. (Maybe I can say it is less than some X number, say 150). And as new data keeps coming in, DaysPassed could be different too.

My requirement is to be able to define a range for these numbers. Like X rows are with 10-30 dayspassed range.

I am not sure how to define this range in sql. I did some research and found something about moving range. Is it the same as what I am looking for? If not, how can I compute the range?

I can do AVG() of all dayspassed and then get AVG() of that average, but I am not sure if this is right.

I think the right way is to able to parse the data and be able to tell that these many rows are in X range. Any ideas?

I am using sql server 2012.

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention which database engine you are using.  The following query would work on any version of Microsoft SQL Server.  If you are not use SQL Server, then you should mention which database engine you are using.

```
Select Count(Case When DaysPassed Between 0 and 9 Then 1 End) As Count_0_to_9,
       Count(Case When DaysPassed Between 10 and 30 Then 1 End) As Count_10_to_30,
       Count(Case When DaysPassed Between 31 and 60 Then 1 End) As Count_31_to_60
From   YourTableNameHere
```

Comment: `sum(Case When DaysPassed Between 0 and 9 Then 1 else 0 End)`

Comment: @juergend I just noticed that the parenthesis were in the wrong place.  It's fixed now.

Comment: Count can not use a case

Comment: @juergend Count can use a case, I encourage you to try it.  This works because I don't specify an ELSE, so NULL would be used and count does not count nulls.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I updated the sql server I am using. I don't know the 0-9 or 10-30 range. I need to see how data is behaving and calculate that range. That's my problem.

Comment: What behavior would control the range?  You don't give any of those details.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to return results within a range, use a WHERE statement with >, < or similar.

Example:

SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE DaysPassed > '20' AND DaysPassed < '40';

If you need this range to be dynamically adjusted, check for the min and max values according to another SELECT statement, store those in variables, and pass them into the one provided above.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This is what I was looking for. Dynamically adjusting the range. Can you help how to calculate that? Do I look at every [dayspassed] and see how many are in a range and group them?

Comment: How are you wanting to determine the min and max of your new range? What is it based upon? What criteria will have to be met for the min and max to get lower/higher, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

You might find the function ntile() useful, if it's ok to have the "ranges" of more-less equal number of items. The function splits your data into bins (buckets, ranges, series...) over a selected column and assigns each element the bin number. Then you can aggregate (sum, average, min, max), grouping by the bin number.

Take a look at: [Want to learn more on NTILE()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14355324/want-to-learn-more-on-ntile)