# Return First 4 Rows, then Repeat for Grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to return data that will ultimately populate a label.
Each label is going onto a box, and the box can only have 4 items in it.
If a delivery has more than 4 items, then I need one label per 4.

Each row of data returned will populate one label, so if the delivery contains 9 items, then I need 3 rows of data returned.

Below is my current query, which is returning all items into a comma separated value using Stuff.

I want it so the first 4 rows for the delivery return in the first row, then the next 4 in the second and so on.

My Field LineOrd returns correctly if there are more than 4 lines on the dispatch.

```
select Distinct
delivery_header.dh_datetime,
delivery_header.dh_number,
order_header.oh_order_number as 'Order No',
order_header_detail.ohd_delivery_name,
order_header_detail.ohd_delivery_address1,
order_header_detail.ohd_delivery_address2,
order_header_detail.ohd_delivery_address3,
order_header_detail.ohd_delivery_town,
order_header_detail.ohd_delivery_county,
order_header_detail.ohd_delivery_postcode,
order_header_detail.ohd_delivery_country,


STUFF((Select  ', '+convert(varchar(50),convert(decimal(8,0),DL.dli_qty))+'x '+OLI.oli_description  
from delivery_header DH join delivery_line_item DL on DL.dli_dh_id = DH.dh_id join order_line_item OLI on OLI.oli_id = DL.dli_oli_id 
Outer APPLY
(select 
case when DelCurLine.CurLine <= 4 
    then '1'
    Else 
        Case when DelCurLine.CurLine <= 8 
        then '2'
        Else '3' 
        End
    End +'-'+order_header.oh_order_number as LineOrd) as StuffLineOrder 

Where DH.dh_id = delivery_header.dh_id And StuffLineOrder.LineOrd = LineOrder.LineOrd
FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')  as Items,

LineOrder.LineOrd



from delivery_header
join delivery_line_item on delivery_line_item.dli_dh_id = delivery_header.dh_id
join order_line_item on order_line_item.oli_id = delivery_line_item.dli_oli_id
join order_header on order_header.oh_id = order_line_item.oli_oh_id
join order_header_detail on order_header_detail.ohd_oh_id = order_header.oh_id
join variant_detail on variant_detail.vad_id = order_line_item.oli_vad_id
join stock_location on stock_location.sl_id = order_line_item.oli_sl_id
Outer APPLY
    (select count(DLI.dli_id) CurLine from delivery_line_item DLI where DLI.dli_dh_id = delivery_header.dh_id and DLI.dli_id <= delivery_line_item.dli_id)
     as DelCurLine


Outer APPLY
(select 
case when DelCurLine.CurLine <= 4 
    then '1'
    Else 
        Case when DelCurLine.CurLine <= 8 
        then '2'
        Else '3' 
        End
    End +'-'+order_header.oh_order_number as LineOrd) as LineOrder   

Outer APPLY
(select convert(varchar(50),convert(decimal(8,0),delivery_line_item.dli_qty))+'x '+order_line_item.oli_description as LineName) as LineName 

where 
delivery_header.dh_datetime between @DateFrom and @DateTo
and stock_location.sl_id = @StockLoc
and (order_header.oh_order_number = @OrderNo or @AllOrder = 1)


order by
delivery_header.dh_datetime,
delivery_header.dh_number,
order_header.oh_order_number,
order_header_detail.ohd_delivery_name,
order_header_detail.ohd_delivery_address1,
order_header_detail.ohd_delivery_address2,
order_header_detail.ohd_delivery_address3,
order_header_detail.ohd_delivery_town,
order_header_detail.ohd_delivery_county,
order_header_detail.ohd_delivery_postcode,
order_header_detail.ohd_delivery_country
```

Comment: you can try using sql "NTILE" function, NTILE helps you in distributing the rows in an ordered partition into a specified number of groups.

Comment: take a look at this...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14355324/want-to-learn-more-on-ntile

Comment: LineOrder is just `CurLine / 4 + 1`. No need for a case expression that only handles three cases. Btw, lots of stuff going on in there and it's hard to read as you've got it laid out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ROW_NUMBER() with a division by 4. This truncate the decimal because numerator is an interger. This give you group number with a maximum of four row in each group. You can then adjust your query to use this group number in a "group by" clause to return grouped rows into a single one.

Exemple here :

```
SELECT  RawData.BoxGroup,
        MIN(dh_datetime),
        MIN(dh_number),
        MIN(order_header.oh_order_number) as 'Order No'
        --And so on
FROM 
    (SELECT BoxGroup = (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) - 1) / 4,
            *
     FROM [TableNameOrQuery]) AS RawData
GROUP BY RawData.BoxGroup
```

Hope this help.