# Loop 10 records at a time and assign it to variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl, ssis-2012

I have a table of 900 records. 
I want to get 10 records at a time and assign it to variable. 
Next time when I run the for each loop task in SSIS, 
it will loop another 10 records and overwrite the variable.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

I have table like this for e.g

```
EMPID
0001
00045
00067
00556
00078
00345
00002
00004
00005
00006
00007
00008
```

this is want I have tried execute sql task to pull 900 records to variable, connect Execute sql task to For each loop, inside for each loop have Data flow task, the source has sql query and destination is table.

```
select * from Dbo.JPKGD0__STP
where EMPID in ?
```

but this will pass each empid in `1` loop , so i wanted to pass 10 empids each time.

Please let me know if I need to use different approach/or other tasks to achieve this.

Comment: Try using NTILE() analytical function which divides your ordered data set into a bucket. eg: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14355324/want-to-learn-more-on-ntile)

Comment: Read the [Tour page](https://www.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

#### Step (1) - Create variables

You have to create two variables of type `int`:

- `@[User::RowCount]` >> type `int`
- `@[User::Counter]` >> type `int`
- `@[User::strQuery]` >> type string

Assign the following expression to `@[User::strQuery]`:

```
"SELECT  EMPID
FROM     Dbo.JPKGD0__STP
ORDER BY EMPIDASC 
OFFSET  " + (DT_WSTR,50)@[User::Counter]  + " ROWS 
FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY "
```

#### Step (2) - Get Row Count

First, add an `Execute SQL Task` with the following command:

```
SELECT Count(*) FROM Dbo.JPKGD0__STP;
```

And store the result in `@[User::RowCount]` variable *([check this link](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/ssis/ssis-basics-using-the-execute-sql-task-to-generate-result-sets/) for more information).*

#### Step (3) - For Loop Container

Now, Add a `For Loop Container` with the following expressions:

- **InitExpression:** `@[User::Counter] = 0`
- **EvalExpression:** `@[User::Counter] < @[User::RowCount]`
- **AssignExpression:** `@[User::Counter] = @[User::Counter] + 10`

Inside the `For loop container`, add a `Data flow task`, with an OLE DB Source and a destination. In the OLE DB Source, select the `Access Mode` as `SQL Command from variable` and select `@[User::strQuery]` as a source.

---

#### References

- [Row Offset in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187998/row-offset-in-sql-server)
- [SQL Server OFFSET FETCH](http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-offset-fetch/)
- [SSIS Basics: Using the Execute SQL Task to Generate Result Sets](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/ssis/ssis-basics-using-the-execute-sql-task-to-generate-result-sets/)
- [ORDER BY Clause (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2012/ms188385(v=sql.110))