# Quarterly data load in SSIS package

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, db2, etl

I just started using the SSIS tool and I need quick help to load data quarterly

Here`s my scenario:

I came up with a query ( source Database: DB2 ) that will extract data from 2010-01-01 to 2021-12-31,(11 years of data) however the data volume is too high ( around 300 M), so I would like to split the data source query to load data into quarter wise.
I tried year wise and still, I am getting more volume of data which my SSIS server is not able to handle.
I have created a year loop to loop it through, in that created a script task into it followed by a data flow task.

For example,

```sql
select * from tab1 where start_date >= '2010-01-01' and end_Date <= '2010-12-31'
```

This I would like to loop it as, ( 4 times load, 1 for each quarter)

```sql
select from tab1 where start_date >= '2010-01-01' and end_Date <= '2010-03-31'
select from tab1 where start_date >= '2010-04-01' and end_Date <= '2010-06-30'
select from tab1 where start_date >= '2010-07-01' and end_Date <= '2010-09-30'
select from tab1 where start_date >= '2010-10-01' and end_Date <= '2010-12-31'
```

Year-wise perfectly works fine, however, I am not getting any idea how do I need to load the data into quarter-wise.
I want to pass each quarter parameters to the source query as parameters, so overall I need to loop to 48 times ( 2010 to 2021 = 11 yrs * 4 quarters)
Any help is greatly appreciated.
I can send screenshots of what I have created for the year loop which is working perfectly fine.

Comment: "data volume is too high... which my SSIS server is not able to handle" - based on what metric? I've funneled billions of rows through SSIS in one shot before without an issue.

Comment: Are you sure you have to filter on BOTH start and end dates, that both are in the same year/quarter, else you will miss some lines ? I think using limit/offset is a better solution but you can filter a quarter using DB2 something like `this_quarter(start_date) = date '2018-04-01'`

Comment: Usually you would target a single column to get values in a range. Something like updateDate between [@start] and [@end]

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution is to use the `OFFSET FETCH` clause to iterate over data. Why looping over data quarterly while using a number of rows is more precise (each iteration will handle the same amount of data). A step-by-step guide is provided in the following article:

- [SQL OFFSET FETCH Feature: Loading Large Volumes of Data Using Limited Resources with SSIS](https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-offset-fetch-feature-loading-large-volumes-of-data-using-limited-resources-with-ssis/)

One thing worth mentioning is that the article handles an SQL Server source, while you are using DB2. Then you should take into consideration any syntax difference while using the `OFFSET FETCH` clause:

- [Getting top n to n rows from db2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54925644/getting-top-n-to-n-rows-from-db2/54932949#54932949)
- [Example: Using the OFFSET clause with a cursor](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.3?topic=cursor-example-using-offset-clause)

---

#### Similar questions:

- [Reading Huge volume of data from Sqlite to SQL Server fails at pre-execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54168322/reading-huge-volume-of-data-from-sqlite-to-sql-server-fails-at-pre-execute/54172707#54172707)
- [Loop 10 records at a time and assign it to variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54521074/loop-10-records-at-a-time-and-assign-it-to-variable/54562372#54562372)
- [SSIS failing to save packages and reboots Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55303314/ssis-failing-to-save-packages-and-reboots-visual-studio/55307412#55307412)

Comment: Thank you, I tried for Sql server and its perfectly working as expected, let me give it a try for DB2

Comment: Check the following answer. It should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54925644/getting-top-n-to-n-rows-from-db2/54932949#54932949

Comment: @user2997871 anything new?